# Counting even numbers in a given list

Tags: python, list, counting

I'm trying to count the numbers in a given list and only count the even numbers. I keep getting a syntax error and don't know what the issue is.

```
x = [1,5,4,7,2,10,8,19,27,26,54,80]

def count_evens(g_list):
    y = 0
    for i in g_list:
        if g_list[i] % 2 = 0:
            y = y + 1
        else:
            y = y + 0
    print(str(y))   

count_evens(x)
```

The syntax error is coming from `if g_list[i] % 2 = 0:` What's wrong about my syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://scipython.com/book/chapter-4-the-core-python-language-ii/examples/assignment-vs-the-comparison-operator/) has a pretty good explanation of Assignment vs Comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> syntax error

You want to compare so use `==` not `=` (single equal is for assignment)

```
if g_list[i] % 2 == 0:
```

> index is out of range

To loop through all elements of the list, you can use this form:

```
for i in g_list:
    if i % 2 == 0:   # No need for g_list[i]
                     # in your for loop,
                     # i is an element from the list, not an index
```

Comment: Oh. My. God. I'm an idiot :/ 
This is what a lack of sleep does to ya, lol

But now it's saying index is out of range. Do I need to make a FOR loop for range and then another one for every [i] in the list?

Comment: @Muldawg2020 when you use `for i in list` you don't need to use `list[i]`, just `i`

Comment: Jeez, now it's working fine. Still getting used to this :/

Thanks a bunch for the help. Really appreciated. I'll close it out once it lets me :)

Answer (score 0):

`g_list[i] % 2 = 0` is an assignment statement (and an illegal one at that since you "Can't assign to an operator").  Assignment statements are not allowed in `if` statements (only expressions).

You want `g_list[i] % 2 == 0` which is a logical expression.